# transparent picturebox on WebBrowser tool

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WebBrowser tool which I'm using to load  .**swf** file, and I need to put a picturebox on it and I need my picture to be transparent, I tried some ideas but nothing worked for me, I tried:

```
pictureBox1.Parent = WebBrowser1;
pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

this makes my picture invisible!

Comment: Maybe try WPF instead of WinForms

Comment: That needs lots of work as I'm working in this project for long time now and moving to WPF will be really hard for me, thanks anyway!

Comment: You can interact with an swf file and pass image data with transparency to it instead of layering it in Winforms, which is very buggy at best.